# Unseting session from external file

Tags: php

The problem is that i have the file "login.php" where i start a session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
```

so according to this i am redirected to a file "main.php" which includes "header.php" where i have a button with a "href" to external file:

```
<a href="logout.php" action="includes/process.php" method="post" ><li>Logout</li></a>
```

This external file includes:

```
<?php
unset($_SESSION['uname']);
?>
```

But the real question in here is when i press this button and goes to "logout.php" and executes the code, why i can back to the previous main page ? And i forgot to tell that have an error:Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\rootFolder\logout.php on line 3

or if i use session_destroy: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in C:\xampp\htdocs\rootFolder\logout.php on line 3

Comment: Probably because of cookies, if you refresh you have no uname in session. I would rather destroy session at logout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `session_destroy()` instead of `unset()`.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

And you have to `start_session()` at the top of all your files.

Comment: I't works man. But the main problem is when i destroy session i have to session_start . I understood you man .thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

on external file "logout.php" you did not started session "**session_start()**".

Use this code in External "logout.php":

```
<?php
   session_start();
   unset($_SESSION['uname']);
?>
```